# Observable<Boolean> method returning null after a catch block

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Given this method:
Why is login status **null** instead of **false**?

```
// this method is called below, I am attempting to return only true or false.
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this
        .loadToken()
        .catch(e => {
            this.logger.info(e); // this is being logged...
            this.token = null;
            return Observable.of(false); // and I specifically return false.
        })
        .map(_ => this.token && this.token.access_token.length > 0);
```

It is being called from **here**

```
return this.authService.isLoggedIn().map(_ => {
    this.logger.info(`authorisation guard :: login status ${_}`);
    if (_)
        return true;
    this.router.navigate(["login"]);
    return Observable.of(false);
}).catch(_ => {
    this.logger.info(`authorisation guard :: login error ${_}`);
    this.router.navigate(["login"]);
    return Observable.of(false);
});
```

The following get's logged:

```
2017-09-09T06:55:46Z [INFO] authorisation guard :: login status null
```

I am expecting

```
2017-09-09T06:55:46Z [INFO] authorisation guard :: login status false
```

Comment: you are having more than one `return` statement and are you subscribing to this observable?

Comment: the observable is being subscribed to by the angular 4 infrastructure - ultimately the value is returned in the authguard `canActivate(): Observable<boolean>`. One may have as many return statements as are precisely needed, no more, and no less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have placed the `catch` before the `map`:

```ts
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
return this
    .loadToken()
    .catch(e => {
        this.logger.info(e);
        this.token = null;
        return Observable.of(false);
    })
    .map(_ => this.token && this.token.access_token.length > 0);
```

That means when an error occurs in `loadToken`, it will be caught by the `catch` and the observable chain will be resumed with the observable returned from the `catch` operator: `Observable.of(false)`.

So, `false` will be passed to `map`, where it will be ignored and the value of `this.token` will be returned - as it will be `null` and will fail the first test in the logical expression.

You most likely want to put the `catch` after the `map`.